# Java Input from formatted file

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to getting input from a file which has various different lines.

e.g. the format is   Book title, Author:Borrower second name  First Name:Borrower state

here's some example lines.

```
The Lord of the Rings, JRR Tolkien:McInnes Elizabeth:13 11 10

Crime And Punishment, Fyodor Dostoyevsky

The Clan Of The Cave Bear, Jean M Auel

The God Of Small Things, Arundhati Roy:Robins Joshua:20 11 10
```

So I tried to use useDelimiter after setting up a scanner, but since some line are shorter I don't no quite what to do.

Comment: Can you change input file formatiing?

Comment: What happens if the book title contains a comma?

Comment: I don't think I can change the format

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution based on regular expressions:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+?),(.+?)(?::(.+?):(\\d+ \\d+ \\d+))?");

        String line;
        while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
            if (m.matches()) {
                String title = m.group(1);
                String author = m.group(2);
                String borrower = m.group(3);
                String data = m.group(4);

                System.out.println("Title:  " + title);
                System.out.println("Author: " + author);
                if (borrower != null) {
                    System.out.println("    Borrower: " + borrower);
                    System.out.println("    Data:     " + data);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

Given your sample input, it prints:

```
Title:  The Lord of the Rings
Author:  JRR Tolkien
    Borrower: McInnes Elizabeth
    Data:     13 11 10

Title:  Crime And Punishment
Author:  Fyodor Dostoyevsky

Title:  The Clan Of The Cave Bear
Author:  Jean M Auel

Title:  The God Of Small Things
Author:  Arundhati Roy
    Borrower: Robins Joshua
    Data:     20 11 10
```

Comment: You sir, take your Regex-fu with a side of Java. I applaud the completeness of the example.

Comment: Much appreciated, this is eactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the file line by line, use the `[^,:]` regular expression to match data in each line (sequential `find` will bring title, author, and borrower, state, if any).

Answer (score 0):

I would split each line (using String.split) passing in the colon as the delimiter. Then use lastIndexOf(',') on the first element returned by split in order to separate the author from the book:

```
public class ReadCrappyInput {

    public static List<String> testData() {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        lines.add("The Lord of the Rings, JRR Tolkien:McInnes Elizabeth:13 11 10");
        lines.add("Crime And Punishment, Fyodor Dostoyevsky");
        lines.add("The Clan Of The Cave Bear, Jean M Auel");
        lines.add("The God Of Small Things, Arundhati Roy:Robins Joshua:20 11 10");
        return lines;
    }

    public Map<String, String> readLine(String line) {
        String[] parts = line.split(":");
        int endOfTitleIndex = parts[0].lastIndexOf(',');
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("title", parts[0].substring(0, endOfTitleIndex));
        map.put("author", parts[0].substring(endOfTitleIndex + 1).trim());    
        if (parts.length > 1) {
            map.put("borrower", parts[1]);
        }
        if (parts.length > 2) {
            map.put("data", parts[2]);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadCrappyInput r = new ReadCrappyInput();
        for (String s : testData()) {
            System.out.println(r.readLine(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use .split()

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("input.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    String line;
    String author;
    String title;
    String borrower;
    String date;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)   {
      (author,title) = line.split(",");

      if (line.contains(":")
        (title,borrower,date) = title.split(":");

      /*** Do what you need to do with the values here ***/
    }

    in.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna adapt your version. Trying to set the delimitter pattern never worked for me, and I wasted alot of time over it.

Answer (score 0):

Why always for such trivial tasks such oversized tools like regular expressions are suggested? Why not simply use the good old `line.indexOf()` or `line.lastIndexOf()` methods?